# How to unit test a function with transitive dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Given the following class which owns two objects, one for modifying documents and one for loading and storing them, how should a proper unit test look like. For testing I'm using `jUnit5` and `Mockito`.

```java
public class Reporter {

private final Modifer modifier;
private final Storage storage;

public Reporter(Modifier modifier, Storage storage) {
    this.modifier = modifier;
    this.storage = storage;
}

public List<Report> modify() {
    List<Report> modificationReports = new LinkedList<>();

    for (Document document : storage.getAll()) {
        //modifies current document, saves new version and deletes old one
        modifier.modify(document);
        storage.save(document);
        storage.delete(document);

        //generates report
        Report modificationReport = new Report();
        modificationReport.setModifiedDocument(document);
        modificationReport.setMessage("Fetched from " + Utils.getNiceFileName(document));
        modificationReport.setExecutionTime(LocalDateTime.now());

        modificationReports.add(modificationReport);
    }
    return modificationReports;
}
}
```

I have following concern. Good practice I'm aware of is that mocked objects shouldn't return mocks. What should then my `storage.getAll` method in for-each loop return so that following code for generating report has valid object to give to `Report` object and `Utils.getNiceFileName` static method.

Also, how to deal with `LocaldateTime.now()` afterwards in asserting which value it should be.

Comment: so if you do not want to return mocks from `storage.getAll()` - return stubs instead? like a list of `Document`s? as to `LocaldateTime` test with `Assertions::notNull`, so that some field is set there

Comment: I could return list of objects of class `Document`, but wouldn't then my test also test functionality of static method `Utils.getNiceFileName`. Also, I've read that using `new` in method is a hard dependency, which should be avoided. Is it good design to try somehow move that creation of report outside this method? Maybe into static method 'Report::buildReportFromDocument` or give this class another dependenciy in form of object of type `ReportBuilder`. Or that's to much complication and granularity.

Comment: `Utils.getNiceFileName` can always be mocked with `Mockito::mockStatic`. I see zero problems testing what you currently have, to be honest.

Comment: Can you explain how can I mock that static method? I know how to mock static method on it's own to test its functionality, but i dont know how to "inject" that mocked method to my modify method.